# How to formulate the query to join more than one table

Tags: php, mysql, join

MY tables are as follows

```
users
id     name
 1     Michael
 2     James
 3     John
 4     Susie
 5     Harvey

products
pid    name          uploader    post_id     views    exclude      groupid
 1     learn_java        2           1         21       0             1
 2     learn_sql         1           2         8        0             2
 3     4 GB DDR3         0           3         5        0             3
 4     love jacket       2           4         0        0             5
 5     1 TB HDD          3           5         12       1             4
 6     kill_ants         3           6         5        0             6
 7     2 TB HDD          2           7         2        0             4
 8     8 GB DDR3         2           8         18       0             3
 9     1 GB DDR2         3           9         7        0             3

product_group
gid    name    category
1      text    1
2      pdf     1
3      ram     2
4      hdd     2
5      leather 0
6      diy     0

product_category
cid    name
1      book
2      electronics

/* forgot about comment field*/
comments
comment_id    post_id    comment
     1            1       ...
     2            1       ...
     3            2       ...
     4            2       ...
     5            2       ...
     6            3       ...
```

**My Goal:**

The product table has 4 types of data.

1. Products with no uploader( uploader = 0 )
2. Products that are in review( exclude = 1 )
3. Products that fall under category = 0(poducts.groupid = product_group.gid AND product_group.category = 0 )
4. Products that are uploaded by an uploader, not in review and not fall under category = 0( uploader != 0, exclude = 1, poducts.groupid = product_group.gid AND product_group.category != 0)

I only have to consider the 4th type of data. I have to exclude the first three types of data. I have to group these data by their uploader. Say, James have uploaded 3 product, Jones have uploaded 2 product and the rest of the user hasn't uploaded anything.

The query should return this

3  James    SUM of views of 3 products
2  Jones    SUM of views of 2 products
0  user1    0
0  user2    0
....
....

So if I consider the data of my table, I want to get the data in follwing order

```
product_num    users.id    users.name    total_views
     3            2           James           41(21+18+2)
     1            3           Jones           7
     1            1           Michael         8
     0            5           Harvey          0/NULL
     0            4           Susie           0/NULL
```

I came up with this.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(pid) as product_num,
       SUM(views) as total_views
       users.*
FROM users
INNER JOIN products ON products.uploader = users.id
INNER JOIN product_group ON products.groupid = product_group.category
WHERE exclude = 0
AND product_group.category != 0
```

Which obviously doesn't work as it doesn't include the users, who hasn't uploaded any product. How to make this work to take these users into account?

**EDIT:**

```sql
SELECT COUNT(pid) as product_num,
       SUM(views) as total_views
       users.*
FROM users
LEFT JOIN products ON products.uploader = users.id
INNER JOIN product_group ON products.groupid = product_group.category
WHERE exclude = 0
AND product_group.category != 0
GROUP BY users.id
ORDER BY product_num
```

It also doesn't take users with 0 upload.

**Second EDIT:**

I have added a comment table(I forgot about it earlier). Is there any way to show the total_number of comments for a user.

Here, James has uploaded product 1,  4, 8. For these post_id is also 1, 4, 8(In real these won't be same). From comments table, these posts have following number of comments 2, 0, 0. So, total number of comment 2.

So, final result should be

```
product_num    users.id    users.name    total_views      total_comments
     3            2           James           41(21+18+2)       2
     1            3           Jones           7                 0/NULL
     1            1           Michael         8                 3
     0            5           Harvey          0/NULL            0/NULL
     0            4           Susie           0/NULL            0/NULL
```

Comment: Perhaps using LEFT JOIN rather than INNER JOIN

Comment: @MarkBaker I tried that, but it gives incorrect product_num, views etc. I can't seem to give the WHERE clause outside the JOINS. If I do that, users with no upload isn't get picked.

Comment: You probably only want to use a LEFT JOIN on `products`, but retain the INNER JOIN on `product_group`

Comment: What values do you want as a result?

Comment: SELECT COUNT(pid) as product_num, SUM(views) as total_views users.* FROM users LEFT OUTER JOIN products ON products.uploader = users.id LEFT OUTER JOIN product_group ON products.groupid = product_group.category WHERE exclude = 0 AND product_group.category != 0

Comment: @c-qjv0xfi still, it doesn't include the user who hasn't uploaded any product. I think the last while clauses are ensuring that.

Comment: @sakibmoon Yes it does. Look into what a left join does.

Comment: @c-qjv0xfi No it doesn't. Exclude is in the products table. sakibmoon, replace WHERE with AND

Comment: Add an `OR exclude IS NULL` and you'll be fine.

Comment: Also, please include full table definitions and a exact description of what you're trying to do.

Comment: `OR exclude IS NULL` doesn't help. The rest of the data are product details and user details. I don't think those will help in any way. I have already provided what I want to achieve. I will try to elaborate that.

Comment: @c-qjv0xfi I have explained more. I hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(pid) as product_num,
       SUM(views) as total_views,
       u.*
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN products p
  ON p.uploader = u.id
LEFT JOIN product_group pg
  ON p.groupid = pg.gid
WHERE p.exclude = 0 
  AND p.uploader <> 0 
  AND pg.category != 0
   OR p.pid is null
GROUP BY u.id
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c94bef/12

To count a number of comments, please add a dependent subquery to the SELECT clause:

```
         SELECT count(*)
         FROM comments c
         WHERE c.post_id = p.post_id
```

in this way:

```
SELECT COUNT(pid) as product_num,
       SUM(views) as total_views,
       ( SELECT count(*)
         FROM comments c
         WHERE c.post_id = p.post_id
       ) As total_comments,
       u.*
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN products p
  ON p.uploader = u.id
LEFT JOIN product_group pg
  ON p.groupid = pg.gid
WHERE p.exclude = 0 
  AND p.uploader <> 0 
  AND pg.category != 0
   OR p.pid is null
GROUP BY u.id
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5c44f/1

Comment: I think the OP wanted the data ordered by `COUNT(pid) DESC`

Comment: Thanks. It works. I am going to accept it. But I have just added another table comment. If you can help me with this too, it will be great.

Comment: I've added an example how to do it to the answer, please take a look at it.